# How to use SendGrid SMTP when application requires email address as username?

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

SendGrid recently moved to a setup where the username for any account to use the SMTP send is "apikey" and the password is the actual apikey. However, I have an application that requires an email address as the SMTP username. Does my SendGrid account have a "virtual email address" that I could use for the username in place of apikey?

Comment: Can you share the details of this application and where it is requiring the username to be an email address?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a virtual email address to be used as the username for the SMTP request. The username must be "apikey".

You will need to take this up with the application you are trying to use as there is no reason to block SMTP servers with usernames that aren't email addresses.

Comment: And what when it's an application from a corporation bigger than Sendgrid and it tells me to take this up with Sendgrid?

Comment: That application remains a user of SendGrid and the only way to get them to update to the latest (which is something that changed years ago) is to encourage them to do so.

Comment: While I can encourage a corporation, as a business I also need a solution and cannot wait for a corporation to respond back. Which means, you just lost a customer as I am forced to not use sendgrid.

Comment: I don’t work at SendGrid anymore, if you wanted direct help with this from SendGrid, I would have suggested reaching out to support not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The point is, what you're suggesting is not helpful. Doesn't matter whether you work with sendgrid or not. Using e-mails as usernames is also within SMTP spec, so good luck arguing with two corporations that both are within spec, but yet incompatible.

Comment: So what is the application that requires the username to be an email?